# My User Profile Update form is not appearing in my template

Tags: django

My User profile update form is not appearing in my template. I can only see 'Update' button and legend name. But I don't see the form. Any ideas?

Here is my forms.py

```
class UserUpdateForm(UserChangeForm):
    username = forms.CharField()
    email = forms.EmailField()

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ['username', 'email' ]
```

Here is my views.py

```
@login_required
def profile(request):
    u_form = UserUpdateForm

    context = {
        'u_form': u_form,
    }
    return render(request, 'users/user_detail.html', context)
```

Here is my template called user_detail.html

```
      <form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        {% csrf_token %}
        <fieldset class="form-group">
          <legend class="border-bottom mb-4">Profile Info</legend>
          {{ u_form|crispy }}
        </fieldset>
        <div class="form-group">
          <button class="btn btn-outline-info" type="submit">Update</button>
        </div>
      </form>
```

Answer (score 0):

try to replace 
from

```
u_form = UserUpdateForm
```

to

```
u_form = UserUpdateForm()
```

in profile def